# cocos2d. Matrix calculations?

Tags: matrix, cocos2d-iphone, point, matrix-multiplication, cgpoint

I draw a graphical primitives using functions `ccDraw...` and I need to calc for example a scale and transition using 3x3 matrices.

How to solve this issue in cocos2d? I can't simply use sprites/nodes because all the calculated points belong to the same object. Is it possible without converting CGPoint->matrix->CGPoint?

Comment: Are you trying to do translation/rotation for 2-D points (e.g. 2x2 rotation matrix extended with distance)?  You could write a simple function to take the translation/rotation and the input point and just do the transformation, returning the result.  There are matrix packages, but that seems a long way to go to get this.

Comment: yes, I meaned 2x2 matrices, but I use 3x3 because it allows to multiply all the transformation matrices.

Comment: Right...so you are using a 3x3 to do the transformation and rotation at the same time (same way 4x4 is used in 3D graphics).  I believe you can use the CGAffineTransform functions to do this...see the answer I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to do scale/rotation on the CGPoints.  You can do this using CGAffineTransform functions and structure that are part of Quartz 2D.

See these references:

1. [Apple's Documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html).
2. [A single example of rotating a rectangle formed by four points.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959216/rotating-cgpoints-civector-cgaffinetransform)
3. [SO Example(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cgaffinetransform).

Was this helpful?

Comment: thanks, I think CGAffineTransform are the most appropriate functions. I didn't thought that they work with the same objects (points) as cocos2d does.

Comment: Rotation and scaling are fairly standard transformations...just be sure to be careful if you are operating on points vs. vectors.